# Need to make v-model dynamic

Tags: vuejs2

I have a questionnaire that has MANY questions. The questions are either an input or a true|false|n/a response. The following allows me to load the questions from the database BUT the v-model isn't working so the responses aren't showing

```
<div v-for="(q, idx) in questions" :key="idx">
    <div v-if="q.type === 'input'">
        <question-input :question="q.question" :name="q.name"
                        v-model="comp.vaf.vendor_info.disassembly['q.name']"> .           </question-input>
    </div>
    <div v-if="q.type === 'boolean'">
        <question-boolean :question="q.question" :name="q.name"
                        v-model="comp.vaf.vendor_info.disassembly['q.name']"> .           </question-boolean>
   </div>
```

Comment: `v-model` is a directive, so `:v-model` does not work.

Comment: that was a typo ... I tried to do :value= and that didn't work either. When I switched back to v-model, I forgot to remove the colon

Comment: Think it should be this way v-model="comp.vaf.vendor_info.disassembly[''+q.name]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **q.name** is a variable hence it should not be in single quote as it would be considered as an property directly rather than considering it as an object value.

Try as below =>

```
 <question-boolean :question="q.question" :name="q.name"
                    v-model="comp.vaf.vendor_info.disassembly[q.name]">
```